# how to run command line with drag and drop folders

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

I have this command line on bat file:

```
mktorrent -l 21 -a http://blablabla/announce <foldertest>
```

but I intend to drag the folder to the file instead of editing for different folder names:

```
mktorrent -l 21 -a http://blablabla/announce <drag and drop here>
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a batchfile like this :

```
@echo off
mktorrent -l 21 -a http://blablabla/announce <%1>
pause
```

And then drop your Folder on your batch.

Comment: Can you put the topic As ANSWERED, please